# Connection refused errors not reported in apache logs

Tags: apache-2.4, http

I have a system where a bunch of raspberry pis access a central server through http. Recently a lot of them have been getting Connection Refused errors (111), but not all of them, and it seems to be a bit random whether their connections will be refused or not. I'm really struggling to debug this, as apache is not reporting these errors in either error.log or access.log. Any clue how I can get these errors in the log so I can start to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the "connection refused" errors on the clients (RasPis) then apache can't log these errors, since it never sees the connections in the first place (the error comes most likely from the TCP/IP stack, not the HTTP layer).

If apache refuses a connection you always get a corresponding HTTP error code (like 403, 404 etc)

Comment: Okay thanks, so how can I debug a problem in the TCP/IP stack? Does that have an error log?